# Proper use of PyQt timer/sleep

Tags: python, qt, timer, pyqt, sleep

How can I properly use the QtTimer?

I have a button connect to a method which basicly does some math, but I want to iterate over it and see the result one at a time, with a delay of 1 second between them.

In normal scriping i would use

```
for i in xrange(10):
   domath(i)
   sleep(1)
```

But in GUI it doesn't work because it freezes the GUI and I can't see the result. Only after 10 seconds I see the last iteration.

I tried the QtTimer but it doesn't seems to work.

```
for i in xrange(10):
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000,lambd: domath(i))
```

it goes directly to the last iteration. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally write something like this:

```
class A(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        Timer.singleShot(100, self.domath())

    Slot()
    def domath(self):
        # do the computation
        self.counter += 1
        if self.counter != 10:
            Timer.singleShot(100, self.domath())
        else:
            self.counter = 0;
```

Disclaimer: even though it looks like PyQt code, this is *only* pseudo code. I have never tested, etc, but the concept is valid in my opinion.

Comment: self.domath() should be self.domath... without brackets. Will update later once I get feedback. The timer value should also be 100 instead of 1000... That will be updated, too. The concept is still the same, however.